# Parallel execution of shell script across cluster nodes

Tags: shell-script, cluster, parallelism

I thought **dsh(Distributed Shell)** will be a good option but when I ran my shell script across my nodes, I didn't get my expected output,

```
dsh -aM -c bash /home/cloudera/bash_script.sh
server2@x.x.x.110: files in folder
server2@x.x.x.110: server2
server1@x.x.x.111: server1
server1@x.x.x.111: sleep time................
server3@x.x.x.112: server3
server3@x.x.x.112: sleep time................
server2@x.x.x.110: sleep time................
```

bash_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do

shopt -s nullglob
#shopt -s dotglob # To include hidden files
files=(/home/cloudera/MyFolder/*)
echo "files in folder" $files[@]

if [  ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ];
then
        for entry in "/home/cloudera/abc"/*
    do
      cp $entry /home/cloudera/Backup
      var=`basename $entry`
      var1=`echo ${var//[.csv]/}`
      echo $var1
      gawk -f abc.awk $entry
      rm -r -f $entry

    done
fi
 echo "server2" 
sleep 5s
 echo "sleep time................"
 sleep 10s
done
```

My script is working properly if I run it without dsh; why this abnormal behavior? By default, dsh can run up to 64 commands in parallel. Does dsh support all bash commands? What is the best option to go for parrallel processing of shell script accross nodes?

Comment: "server2" message is hardcoded, which does not match the output, I suppose scripts have the same name but are different on each servers ?

Comment: have you considered porting it to Python Fabric?

Answer (score 2):

Before you start porting try with GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j0 --tag --line-buffer ssh {} bash /home/cloudera/bash_script.sh ::: server1 server2 server3
```

You need version 20130822 or later for --line-buffer.